# Jenkins cannot connect to EC2 using private key, but I can connect using Putty

Tags: jenkins, amazon-ec2, ssh, ssh-keys

I recently inherited a Jenkins instance running on an AWS EC2 server. It has several pipelines to different EC2 servers that are running successfully. I'm having trouble adding a new node to a new EC2 web server.

I have an account on that new web server named `jenkins`. I generated keys, added the `ssh-rsa` key to `~/.ssh/authorized_keys`, and verified I was able to connect with the jenkins user via Putty.

[image]

In Jenkins, under **Dashboard > Credentials > System > Global Credentials**, I created new credentials as follows:

1. Username: `jenkins`
2. Private Key -> Enter Key Directly: Pasted in the key beginning with "BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY":

[image]

Finally, I created a new node using those credentials, to connect via SSH and use the "Known hosts file Verification Strategy."

[image]

Unfortunately, I'm getting the following error when I attempt to launch the agent:

> [01/04/22 22:16:43] [SSH] WARNING: No entry currently exists in the
> Known Hosts file for this host. Connections will be denied until this
> new host and its associated key is added to the Known Hosts file. Key
> exchange was not finished, connection is closed.

I verified I have the correct Host name configured in my node.
I don't know what I'm missing here, especially since I can connect via Putty.

Suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you added the new node to the known hosts file on the Controller node?
I assume Putty was your local machine rather than the controller?

See this support article for details
https://support.cloudbees.com/hc/en-us/articles/115000073552-Host-Key-Verification-for-SSH-Agents#knowhostsfileverificationstrategy

Comment: That did it, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like your system doesn't allow for automatic hostkeys into the `known_hosts` file. You can check for the `UpdateHostKeys` flag in either your user, system, or potentially whatever user Jenkins runs under, SSH Config file. You can read more about the specific flag I'm talking about [here](http://man.openbsd.org/OpenBSD-current/man5/ssh_config.5#UpdateHostKeys).

If you need to add that hostkey manually, [here's](https://www.techrepublic.com/article/how-to-easily-add-an-ssh-fingerprint-to-your-knownhosts-file-in-linux/) a nice write up for how to do it.